# With three.js is there a way to break a shape into random pieces?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am able to create a random shape using `PolyhedronGeometry();`, and `MorphTarget` but I'm curious if there is a way to break an existing shape into pieces?  Such as a rock into random shaped pebbles?